# How can I install and use JAI with Eclipse

Tags: java, jai

I am following a tutorial that asks me to include

```
import javax.media.jai.TiledImage;
```

So basically I will have to install JAI. This is my very first beginning in Java though, and the first time I use Eclipse thus I have some problems with doing so.

Actually I cant even find where I am supposed to download it from as all links I find are quite old.

So my question has two parts:

Where can I find the official release of JAI?

How can I install it in Eclipse?

Comment: So.. are you asking us where you can download it? If you are, you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: As @mmking asks, are you asking where to download from or how to install?

Comment: I did realize I did not actually ask anything and edited the 'question' just seconds before your comment .)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for a JAR file that contains a class you'd need to use, the best place to start looking from is the [FindJAR](http://www.findjar.com) site. This will tell you that `TiledImage` is included in `jai-core-1.1.3-alpha.jar` which can be downloaded from a [mirror site](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/geoserver/jai/jars/jai-core-1.1.3-alpha.jar).

The JAI project is no longer active and many of the JARs can't be found in public Maven repositories, so if you have a choice, you could consider using a more active project such as [Apache Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/).

Comment: Quite interesting answer too, especially the last recommendation. I marking this as the correct answer in order to save anyone who might read this to maybe consider using something other than JAI since it is not actively developed anymore. Both answers contain very interesting information nonetheless.

Comment: Unfortunately, Java lacks a good _de facto_ cross-platform imaging library. There are Java wrappers to applications such as ImageMagick, and also imaging software written in Java (ImageJ / FIJI), but they all rely on native code. Commons Imaging seems like a promising Java-only image library, even though there is no "stable" release yet. Hope this helped!

Comment: I'm doing my best to provide pure Java support for most image formats supported by JAI: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys. Just so you know. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to search what is the latest version of a jar file from [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jaitools/jt-all/1.2.0). Also you can download it from here. It says the latest version of this jar is 1.2.

In eclipse you don't need to install the jar. It is a good way to make a `lib` directory under your main project directory. After place all of your jar file in  this directory. Then add all those jar file in `buildpath` using eclipse. 
You can see a step by step instruction **[How to Add JARs to Eclipse Buildpath](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)**

Hope it will help.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think you forgot the second link though. +1 for the first link, there seems to be many interesting things in there.

Comment: I have just edit the second link. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: `jt-all-1.2.0.jar` does not contain the class the OP is looking for. Instead the class is in `jai-core-1.1.3-alpha.jar`; see my answer for the correct download link.